# Find the all customer names consisting of three or more words (for example King George V)

Tags: mysql, sql

## schema:

> customers(name, mailid, city)

## What to find:

Find all customer names consisting of three or more words (for example `King George V`).

## What I tried:

```
select name from customers 
 where name like 
  '%[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]% %[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]% %[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]%'
```

## what is surprising me:

If I am trying for two words (removing the last `%[A-Za-z0-9]%` from my query), its working fine but its not working for three words :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MySQL Solution**:

If a `name` has words separated by *space* character, then,

Try the following:

```
select name from customers 
where ( length( name )
        -
        length( replace( name, ' ', '' ) ) + 1
      ) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In t-sql, the like clause can contain multiple wild card checks - eg: 
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Name like '% % %'

will return those Names where two spaces are contained.

Answer (score 0):

If you are consistent with the spacing between names, you could use this logic

```
SELECT  LENGTH(name)-LENGTH(REPLACE(name,' ',''))
FROM customers
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this too if your sql dont have length function ( which is the situation I have when I'm doing an online exercies...) Inspired by answers above

```
SELECT name FROM customers WHERE (replace(name,' ','*')) LIKE '%*%*%'
```